# Citrix wfapi/mfcom working example

Tags: c#, citrix, virtual-channel

I installed Wfapi SDK. All standard examples for Wfapi in VB and C work just fine but I wanted to wrap the dll to use it in C#. However the example from the official site [VSSDKNET Wrapper](http://community.citrix.com/display/xa/More+information+on+Citrix+Virtual+Channel+in+the+.NET+Framework)  converted into VS10 standard and compiled  gives me the `incorrect format HResult : 0x8007000B` error and even changing the example (compiling to x64 cpu or changing some types according to msdn default type marshaling in wrapper) didn't help.
At that point I decided to try luck with MFcom (downloaded the MPSSDK). The standart example from that sdk gives me errors finding referenced mfcom lib. So I even can't compile it.

Developer machine - WinXP SP3 with VS10.

Server - Win Server 2008 R2 standard SP1, 64bit, XenApp 6

As for the goal of all this - I want to have an ability to create my own VirtualChannels from Server to Client machine and exchange some info through them.

Can someone clearly explain me what should I download, install and change in the code to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to create your own virtual channel then those are the wrong SDKs to be looking at. Citrix has a dedicated SDK for creating your own VCs. You can find more information about it here:

http://community.citrix.com/display/xa/Virtual+Channel+SDK

For questions about the SDK there is a dedicated forum for it here:

http://forums.citrix.com/forum.jspa?forumID=46

I have personally never used this SDK, so I cannot give you specific information about how to install/setup/compile/configure/etc.

Regards,
Donovan